# Template - Parent Detailview w/ child for loop list

Tags: django, django-templates

I've been trying solutions that have been suggested for others in similar situations, however almost all questions are regarding bizzarely unusual scenarios and I've been unable to adapt them to my situation.

**I'd like a for loop of child information in a parent's DetailView**

Models

```
class Projects(models.Model):
      fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Projects_items(models.Model):
      itemName = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      fk_project = models.ForeignKey(Projects,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item")
      value = models.FloatField()
```

Views

```
class projects(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Projects
    fields = [
    'name',
    ]
    template_name = 'games/project_details.html'
    context_object_name = 'projects'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.fk_user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        # return super().form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.fk_user:
            return True
        return False
```

Template - projects_details

```
{% extends './underlay.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'details.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">

{% block content %}
<H2>LIST OF ITEMS BELONGING TO THIS PROJECT</H2>
 
 ?

SOMETHING LIKE:
{% for projects.item in projects %}
{{ projects.item.itemName }} - {{ projects.item.value }}
{% endfor %}

THIS GAVE AN ERROR OF 'PROJECTS' OBJECT NOT ITERABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstfully, change name of classes to singular, like `Project` and `Projects_item`, because it's confusing.

Secondly, change `related_name` of `ForeignKey` to `related_name="items"`.

Then in template you can get all related `Projects_items` like this:

```
{% for item in project.items.all %}
    {{ item.itemName }} - {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: beautiful thank you